# Using app url scheme on android

Tags: android, url

We have both an IOS and Android app that has custom URL schemes.  When we send the scheme via email, the IOS has no problem.  But when the Android gets the email, it strips away the link and displays it as pure text.

Here is the URL scheme:

callplease://startup

I have tried typing it into email as well as inserting it as a link.  Regardless, the email client strips everything away.

I also tried creating a web page with this code:

launch the app

When I bring it up in the Chrome browser on my Android and click on the link, I get the error message that the web page is not available and the URL scheme is known (ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME).

We have tested this out in Eclipse and everything is fine with the app.  There has to be a way to send the link in an email and have it launch the app.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just curious: Which part of the Android documentation made you think that Chrome (or any Android browser) would recognize `callplease://startup` to invoke your app?

Answer (score 1):

Android by default uses [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) to create clickable links. As seen there, the acceptable types of content to linkify are:

- Email Addresses
- Map Addresses
- Phone Numbers
- Web URLs

And per the [Linkify source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java) (line 219 at this time), the only web urls that are automatically linkified are:

- "http://"
- "https://"
- "rtsp://"

You can certainly handle an http equivalent URL by registering an ACTION_VIEW `intent-filter` for the http address to point to the same location as your custom URL, but other apps will not recognize your custom URL scheme as a valid link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an `intent-filter`in the manifest much like this for the Activity you wish to have open the scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="callplease" />
</intent-filter>
```